# Enable archivelog

Tags: oracle, archive-log

[image: Screen Shot here]I'm trying to enable archivelog mode in Oracle database. For that I shutdown the services and used startup mount. Instead of database getting mounted, I'm getting error ORA- 12528 TNS - All instances are blocking new connections.

Any one can guide on this.

Comment: Use a local connection: `sqlplus / as sysdba`. What you tried will not work without static listener registration.

Comment: as a work around you can try a local connection to the database if this is possible. connect to the server and connect using sqlplus and 'connect / as sysdba'

Answer (score -2):

in which state your database was at the point you issue the shutdown command?
Maybe the unregister in listener was incomplete.
try:

1. stop database

   shutdown immediate
2. restart listener

   lsnrctl restart
3. start database

   startup mount

Comment: sorry, but that is wrong, Besides that , how should one issue a "shutdown immediate" if one cannot connect to the database

Comment: you dont need a listener for os authentification as sysdba. Connect as sysdba shoud be possible

Comment: I know, but the OP is not able to connect to the database to  to do a "startup mount", so why do you think he is able to connect to the database to do a "shutdow immediate"?

Comment: db is already shutdown.. so listener restart could be help.